# GeckoView never passes referrer path/query

Tags: android, kotlin, geckoview

I'm trying to pass a referrer with `GeckoSession.Loader`, given that no referrers are passed at all by default with `GeckoView`. However, only the origin is ever passed. My code (actual URLs obfuscated):

```
val url = "https://www.example.com/path?query=example"
val referrer = "https://www.example.com/referrer_path?query=example"
val loader = GeckoSession.Loader().uri(url).referrer(referrer)
session.load(loader)
```

The page at `url` does not use a meta referrer. Given the loaded URL and the referrer URL are `same-origin` and `GeckoView` uses `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` by default, I expect `document.referrer` on the loaded page (at `url`) to be `"https://www.example.com/referrer_path?query=example"`; however, it is always just `"https://www.example.com/"`.

Is this expected? What am I missing or doing wrong here?